# How do I make a regex NOT match when I first find something unwanted

Tags: regex

I want to use a regex to find a particular string in my sample, but I want the regex to fail if I first find another string.  Let me give an example:

Match `find_me` only if we do not first encounter `stop_here`.  (I don't care if `stop_here` occurs later in the sample.)

So, this should match:

`blah blah find_me blah stop_here`

But this shouldn't:

`blah blah stop_here blah find_me`

(I'm using the .NET regex engine)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
^(?:(?!stop_here).)*find_me
```

Comment: I knew I wanted a look-ahead, but I couldn't figure out how to use it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of the .NET regex engine, but I would just do a regexp search for find_me or stop_here and then check which one matched.  In perl:

```
if ($stuff =~ /(find_me|stop_here)/) {
  if ($1 == "find_me") {
    ...
  } elsif ($1 == "stop_here") {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I didn't mention it in my question, but this is actually part of a larger regex, so I prefer the accepted answer, but yours is certainly easier to read.  Thanks!